# Why does the border color render to background-color when set to transparent?

Tags: html, css

I am creating some CSS illustrations and I want to create a triangular shape. But, you will see that the transparent border is not actually *transparent*. It is of the same color as the background-color of the `<div>`.

```css
.triangle {
  background-color: #ff3e30;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #ff3e30;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;    /* This is the culprit */
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

But, when I use a different color, it shows that the shape created *should* be a triangle if the border *is* transparent.

```css
.triangle {
  background-color: #ff3e30;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #ff3e30;
  border-left: 50px solid black;    /* Changed to black */
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

So, how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default the background cover the border area. You can change this behavior using `background-clip` (or simply remove it like stated by @Mahmood Kiaheyrati)

```css
.triangle {
  background-color: #ff3e30;
  background-clip:padding-box;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #ff3e30;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning the `background-clip` property. Its really helpful when someone provides multiple solutions or alternates.

Answer (score 3):

The Background-color was in the way.

```css
.triangle {
  //background-color: #ff3e30;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #ff3e30;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing well.

Here in this link you will find some triangle shape. You can practice for better understanding that how it works.

https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

css for triangle-bottomleft

```
#triangle-bottomleft {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

html

```
<div id="triangle-bottomleft"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The background-color was causing the problem.